# CNNs generalizing to same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I'am using tensorflow 1.10, and training on subset of retinopathy dataset. The problem is that it always predicts the class that occurs the most. In my case it is the class 0. so, I did a little digging and came across something called under-sampling. I left out all the 0(just to see what happens) it only predicts the class 2 after 0. apparently class 2 has highest frequency. 
Here is the code for optimization:

```
def data_pipe_line(data,checkpoint_path,i_data=None,epoch=5):

place_X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,500,400,3],name='p1')
place_Y=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None],name='p2')
infer_data=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((place_X,place_Y))
infer_data=infer_data.batch(100)
iterator=tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(data.output_types,data.output_shapes)
next_image,next_label=iterator.get_next()
Y=tf.one_hot(next_label,5)
Y=tf.cast(Y,tf.float32)
logits=model(next_image,0.7)
print(logits)
print(Y)
train_iterator=iterator.make_initializer(data,name='train_op')
inference_iterator_op=iterator.make_initializer(infer_data,name='inference_op')



with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    loss=tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y,logits=logits),name='cost')
    #the learning rate is so low because the batch-size is very small and has a lot of noise
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0005).minimize(loss)
    #getting the accuracy
    prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1,name='pred')
    equality=tf.equal(prediction,tf.argmax(Y,1))
    accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(equality,tf.float32))
    init_op=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    tf.summary.scalar("loss",loss)
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy",accuracy)
    merged=tf.summary.merge_all()
    saver=tf.train.Saver()



j=0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("./nn_logs",sess.graph)
    sess.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(epoch):
        sess.run(train_iterator)
        while True:
            try:
                #print(sess.run(logits))
                j=j+1 
                summary = sess.run(merged)
                _,acc,l=sess.run([optimizer,accuracy,loss]) 
                if(j%20==0 or j==1):
                    print("iters: {}, loss: {:.10f}, training accuracy: {:.2f}".format(j, l, acc*100))
                writer.add_summary(summary,j)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:

                break
    saver.save(sess,checkpoint_path)
```

The model is training well, loss goes down for sometime and then it just fluctuates there(in a range of 5). the accuracy of course fluctuates a lot as it is only predicting 1 class.

Comment: [This might help](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17219/how-to-do-imbalanced-classification-in-deep-learning-tensorflow-rnn)

Answer (score 1):

By what you said, I can conclude that your dataset is highly unbalanced and then the model that you trained didn't generalized your data at all. The model then predicts the class with most samples, because at a random guess there's more chance that it would be the correct label. To try to solve this, one approach is to balance your data.

## Under Sampling

One way to do that is using the technique called under sampling, as you have finded out. In your training set you verify the class that has less samples, and then you pass to the training phase that same number of samples of each class. The selection is done at random. The test set remains intact.

## Over Sampling

Here you take the contrary way: take the class with more samples and make all other classes have that same amount of samples. The simplest way to do that is repeating at random your samples. Another way would be augmenting your data.

You can also can weight the loss function. For this, G. Anderson already linked a good [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17219/how-to-do-imbalanced-classification-in-deep-learning-tensorflow-rnn) about.

## The intuiton behind weighted the loss

When the classes are unbalanced, the model understands that if it get the wrong label for the class with less samples it will be poorly penalized for that mistake. Once they have less samples of that class, that mistake will occur less often and when it occur it will have the same impact of a mistake of one class with more samples. So what the weighted loss do is give more importance for a mistake in the class with less samples and less importance for a mistake in the class with more samples.

**Answering the question in the commentary**

Remember: the loss function is used to correct the learned model weights and, when you add another dense layer in your model, you are doing changes that will affect the learning step. So your model will still attributing the same importance level to the mistakes in every class.

Comment: Hi, so I was looking at one other soln to this problem, weighted loss. What I'm not getting is what is the difference between it and adding another dense layer?

Comment: @KislayKunal check out my explanation about the weighted loss